# Convert list of list in a dataframe of list

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a list of list like this:

A = [['1250', '22200', '43110'], [True, True, True]]

My goal is to convert such list into a dataframe with 2 columns and just one row. If I type pd.DataFrame(A) I get 3 rows and 2 column. What should I do in order to get the result I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wrap it in one more list:

```py
pd.DataFrame([A])
                      0                   1
0  [1250, 22200, 43110]  [True, True, True]
```